# wsadmin jython script exit code to calling script

Tags: batch-file, automation, websphere, exit-code

I am writing batch and bash scripts to automate some websphere tasks.

I need to get the exit code of myscipt.jy back to the calling script,
jython script

```
#----------myscipt.jy-----------
#I am testing exit status
import sys;
sys.exit(1)
```

and the batch script is

```
REM superduper.cmd
profiles\myprofile\bin\wsadmin -lang jython -f myscript.jy
echo myscript.jy exited with %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the following workaround to get around the problem

First write a key/value pair to a file from jython

```
#----------myscipt.jy-----------
#I am testing exit status
import sys;
logFile = open(heaplog, "w")
logFile.write("HEAPSIZECHANGED=1")
logFile.close()
sys.exit(1)
```

and then load the key/value as env. variable in batch and use it

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('type "%HEAPLOG%" ^| findstr /V /B #') DO SET %%i
IF !HEAPSIZECHANGED! EQU 1 CALL :_restartServer
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the changes in Jython V2.7 [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/rxml_jython27.html#rxml_jython27__sec3), the way to detect exit code can be as follows.

```
#----------myscipt.jy-----------
#I am testing exit status
import os
os._exit(1)
```

and the batch script is

```
REM superduper.cmd
profiles\myprofile\bin\wsadmin -lang jython -f myscript.jy
echo myscript.jy exited with %ERRORLEVEL%
```